# Can we say the above iteration has a unique fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have a question about the fixed point theorem about Picard iteration. If we have some initial starting of functions $R_0, K_0$ defined on closed interval (e.g. $R:t\mapsto [0,T]$) with the following iterative updates:
$$
R_{m+1}=\Psi^{(1)}(R_m, K_m, G), K_{m+1}=\Psi^{(2)}(R_m, K_m, G),
$$
where $G$ is a fixed function and $\Psi^{(1)}, \Psi^{(2)}$ are two mappings.

If we can show that as $m\to \infty$,
$$
\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|R_{m+1}-R_m|\le 2^m\frac{T^m}{m!}\to 0
$$
and $\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|K_{m+1}-K_m|\to 0$.

Can we say the above iteration has a unique fixed point? Then can we say $
R_{m+1}=\Psi^{(1)}(G), K_{m+1}=\Psi^{(2)}(G)
$?

I found the Banach Fixed Point Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), but it needs to check  that there exists $\gamma\in [0,1)$ such that
$$
|\Psi^{(1)}(R_m, K_m, G)-\Psi^{(1)}(R'_m, K_m, G)|\le \gamma d((R_m, K_m, G), (R'_m, K_m, G))
$$

Comment: You can get convergence and uniqueness from such a type of inequality for a fixed-point iteration, but that requires that $F^m$ has a Lipschitz constant $\frac{(2T)^m}{m!}$, not just one specific iteration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann What is $F$? Sorry, can you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, missed to add this. $F$ is any generic fixed-point iteration function $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$. Another claim of similar potency is that if $F^m$ is contracting for and $m$, then $F$ has a unique fixed point. /// As it is, your inequalities only ensure that the limit of $R_m$ exists, but not that the $K_m$ have a limit. There is nothing that would tell if the limit of the $R_m$ changes if the initial points are changed.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Does it means that $|R_{m+1}-R_m|=|\Psi^{(1)}(R_m)-\Psi^{(1)}(R_{m-1})|\le \frac{(2T)^m}{m!}|R_1-R_0|\le \frac{(2T)^m}{m!}$ implies $\Psi$ has a Lipschitz constant $ \frac{(2T)^m}{m!}$? Here I assume that $|R_1-R_0|<1.$

Comment: @LutzLehmann For $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$, you mean that we need $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|=|F(x_n)-F(x_{n-1})|\le 2T |x_n-x_{n-1}|$ and  $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\le (2T)^n/n!$?

Comment: Nearly that, $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|F^n(x_1)-F^n(x_0)|\le \frac{(2T)^n}{n!}|x_1-x_0|$.